# Losses keep increasing within iteration

Tags: python, neural-network, spacy, loss-function

I am just a little confused on the following:
I am training a neural network and have it print out the losses. I am training it over 4 iterations just to try it out, and use batches. I normally see loss functions as parabolas, where the losses would decrease to a minimum point before increasing again. But my losses keep increasing as the iteration progresses.

For example, let's say there are 100 batches in each iteration. In iteration 0, losses started at 26.3 (batch 0) and went up to 1500.7 (batch 100). In iteration 1, it started at 2.4e-14 and went up to 80.8.

I am following an example from spacy (https://spacy.io/usage/examples#training-ner). Should I be comparing the losses across batches instead (i.e. if I take the points from all of the batch 0s it should resemble a parabola)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the exact same code as linked, this behaviour is to be expected.

```
for itn in range(n_iter):
        random.shuffle(TRAIN_DATA)
        losses = {}
        # batch up the examples using spaCy's minibatch
        batches = minibatch(TRAIN_DATA, size=compounding(4.0, 32.0, 1.001))
        for batch in batches:
            texts, annotations = zip(*batch)
            nlp.update(
                texts,  # batch of texts
                annotations,  # batch of annotations
                drop=0.5,  # dropout - make it harder to memorise data
                losses=losses,
            )
        print("Losses", losses)
```

An "iteration" is the outer loop:  `for itn in range(n_iter)`. And from the sample code you can also infer that `losses` is being reset every iteration. The `nlp.update` call will actually increment the appropriate loss in each call, i.e. with each `batch` that it processes.

So yes: the loss increases WITHIN an iteration, for each batch that you process. To check whether your model is actually learning anything, you need to check the loss across iterations, similar as how the `print` statement in the original snippet only prints after looping through the batches, not during.

Hope that helps!

Comment: PS: note that the loss here, is measured on the training set. So typically you wouldn't see that going back up (after initial decrease), but it would actually keep decreasing. This is why ideally, you need an additional dev/test dataset to measure performance on to identify that point that the model would start overfitting.

Comment: Is development data the same as test data? I've been seeing 'development' data around spacy but didn't exactly know what it meant. And thanks this definitely clears it up!

Comment: You're welcome! I personally would recommend using at least 3 separate datasets: 1 for training (`update` loop), 1 for "development" (measure performance during training, determine hyperparameters such as #of iterations, batch size, etc), and 1 for actual "test", i.e. the test set is a set you use only ONCE, at the very end of the design & training of your model, to determine the final, realistic, performance of your model. Because it will be overfitted on the training set (because of the trained weights) and on the development set (because of the hyperparameter tuning)

Comment: Thanks! But I'm just confused on how to use the development set to measure performance during training and basically use it overall.

Comment: You can read in your dev dataset when printing the training loss, and print the dev accuracy alongside it. You can use `Language.evaluate()` for this purpose, see https://spacy.io/api/language#evaluate.